# SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1367

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, servlets

I have an AngularJS front-end, which uses Restangular to make a call to the backend through a Java Servlet, which returns JSON data, which is then parsed to make a chart using Charts.js

**Angular Factory**

```
app.factory('graphService', function($http, Restangular) {

            var exports = {};

            exports.getRestangular = function() {
                // return Restangular.setBaseUrl("/api");
                return Restangular.setBaseUrl("/apm/graph");
            };

            exports.getGraphDataDC = function(dcName) {
                return exports.getRestangular().all("graphData/DC/" + dcName).getList();
            };
}
```

**Angular UI RestangularCall**

```
graphService.getGraphDataDC(item.name).then(function (data) {
                        $scope.summary = data;
                        $scope.JSONtoArrays(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.createChart();
                    }, function(data) {
                        //Error
                    });
```

**Java Servlet**

```
try
{
        dcData = persistance.getSummaryDelaysDC80Perc(from, to, pathInfo[pathInfo.length-1]);
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not load data form database, reason: {}", e);
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
        // parse to json
    json = ThreadsafeUtils.getGsonInstance(pretty).toJson(dcData);
    LOGGER.debug(dcData.size() + " summary entries were read");

        out.write(json);
        break;
}
```

**Persistence Facade** This is the function being called by the Servlet

```
public List<SummaryDelaysDataCenter80Perc> getSummaryDelaysDC80Perc(Date from, Date to, String dcName)  throws RuntimeException {
        List<SummaryDelaysDataCenter80Perc> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
        java.sql.Date minDate;
        java.sql.Date maxDate;
        String call;
        if (from != null)
            minDate = new java.sql.Date(from.getTime());
        else
            minDate = Utils.getDBMinDate();

        if (to != null) {
            maxDate = new java.sql.Date(to.getTime());
        } else {
            maxDate = Utils.getDBMaxDate();
        }
        call = "CALL " + summaryDelaysDCProcedureName + "(?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            //prepare statement
            java.sql.Connection connection = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
            java.sql.CallableStatement cst = connection.prepareCall(call);
            //set parameters
            cst.setDate(1, minDate, c);
            cst.setDate(2, maxDate, c);
            cst.setString(3, dcName);
            // execute statement and retrieve result
            cst.execute();
            ResultSet rs = cst.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                SummaryDelaysDataCenter80Perc sdeldc80 = new SummaryDelaysDataCenter80Perc();
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
                String strDate = dateFormat.format(rs.getTimestamp(1));
                sdeldc80.setName(rs.getString(2));
                sdeldc80.setDate(strDate);
                sdeldc80.setPerc80serverdelay(Double.toString(rs.getDouble(3)));
                sdeldc80.setPerc80networkdelay(Double.toString(rs.getDouble(4)));
                sdeldc80.setPerc80clientdelay(Double.toString(rs.getDouble(5)));
                sdeldc80.setPerc80roundtrips(Long.toString(rs.getLong(6)));
                result.add(sdeldc80);
            }
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("StoredProcedureCall was not successful", e);
        }
        return result;

    }
```

The json variable after calling getGsonInstance().toJson() looks like:

```
[{"Name" : "WER", "Count" : 90, "Date": "2016-05-25" }, 
{"Name" : "TWK", "Count" : 17, "Date": "2016-05-26"  }, 
{"Name" : "XPR", "Count" : 26, "Date": "2016-05-27"  }]
```

The Java Servlet code executes completely, but before `$scope.summary` is assigned the values retrieved, the code error with `Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1367`.

The JSON string does have a size of 1367 chars, but that means the last position 1366, so I'm not sure why it says error at 1367.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You have to quote the `Date` values like `"2016-05-25"`.

Comment: @str my bad I missed that. I just corrected it.

Comment: `at position 1367`. The posted JSON does not appear that long.

Comment: I just posted a sample of what the JSON looks like.

Comment: paste your json in tools like http://json.parser.online.fr/. This helps you to see which part is invalid

Comment: @MikeHoltkamp is the website loading for you? Its not for me.

Comment: Provide your complete servlet code, It seems you are treating JSONArray as JSONObject.

Comment: try this one https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or google for json validators

Comment: I'm never calling JSON.parse, so why is this error showing up? Is there any part in my code that's calling JSON.parse?

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh added the persistence function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The issue was a missing break statement in the persistence facade.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.parse(data). Then perform other operations.

Comment: Where? In the servlet?

Comment: $scope.summary = JSON.parse(data).